# Dedicated CPU allocation to zone in Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, cpu, solaris-zones

I have created a zone called `web` in Solaris 11. Now I want to allocate one dedicated CPU resource to that zone. But it's throwing an error: "No such entry".

I did the following...

```
zonecfg:web> select dedicated-cpu  
select dedicated-cpu: No such entry  
zonecfg:web>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this hope this works. This sets up the zone so it has between 1 and 4 CPU's for its exclusive use, or you may configure as per your requirement.

```
# zonecfg -z zone_name
# add dedicated-cpu
# set ncpus=1-4
# set importance=2
# end
# verify
# commit
# exit
```

To Confirm

`zonecfg -z zone_name info`